# Examples of proofs that are easiest by double counting.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

What's an example of a proof that's easiest to do by double counting? I've read examples of double counting on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/double-counting-definition/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)), but most of claims seem to be more easily provable with direct proofs. I suspect I'm missing some of the rationale behind double counting as a proof strategy.

Does anyone know of some simple proofs that are easiest with double counting and harder with other proof techniques?

Comment: Search here for "combinatorial proof" and you will see dozens of examples.

Comment: For a few quick examples off the top of my head, $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n\binom{t}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: At it's heart, double counting is just a fancy way of saying "we count this thing in 2 different ways". Very often proofs are by double counting, but just not explicitly mentioned. EG Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion is proven by "count the number of sets" in 2 different ways, and is a form of double counting. $\quad$ For a more advanced applications, look up cases where incidence matrices are set up and we count column pairs (again in 2 different ways). (I'm not referring to those which use linear algebra properties)

Comment: If you want, I can email you my notes for double counting + incidence matrix. They have a ton of examples from olympiad problems (few solutions, but easily googleable).